# Recloning an object if the object cloned changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone, watch

I am working on a pricing app that has a lot going on and different parts of the page are loaded from different scripts templates, ie Backbone loading into a PHP template.

I have a sidebar that dynamically updates the user's total balance. On mobile that sidebar is hidden in a dropdown menu.  Long story short, I have cloned that html "price" value into another place on the page and need it to update whenever the original (hidden) value updates.  I have cloned the value like this:

```
            $(window).bind("load", function() {
                $('#quote_scrollbox .price').clone().insertAfter('.specifications-toggle img');
            });
```

and inserted into the proper place. However, whenever the .price value updates, I need to update it in its new place as well.  This value updates often as this is a pricing app that updates with each user input.  Can someone please give me some help on this one?

Comment: Thanks for the input, but that doesn't help.  I need the cloned value to update whenever the value it was cloned from updates on the front-end

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `input` event , `.filter()` to match elements not having same value as current element value , `.val(function(index, val) {})` to set each `input` element to current element value

```js
$(window).bind("load", function() {
  var input = $(".price");
  var clone = input.clone(true, true);
  clone.insertAfter("div");

  $(".price").on("input", function(e) {
    var elem = e.target;
    $(".price").filter(function(i, el) {
      return el.value !== elem.value
    }).val(function(i, val) {
      return elem.value
    });
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="price" />
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this does not work.  The cloned element is not updating when the original value that it was cloned from changes

Comment: @user3633970 _"Thanks for the help, but this does not work. The cloned element is not updating when the original value that it was cloned from changes "_ Can include `html` at Question ? , create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?